# Do penguins "test the ice"?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

Do penguins have a way to test the ice that they stand on to ensure that the ice will not break? In other words, do penguins make sure that they will not fall into the ice before stepping onto it?

I have conducted research but have come up short, which made me assume that penguins *don't* test the ice. However, I wanted to make sure before I just made an assumption.

Comment: What would happen to a penguin if the ice did break under their weight?

Comment: @BryanKrause They would fall into the water; they would be startled, but if the conditions are right, then they will be able to swim under the water, correct?

Comment: I could also envision a scenario that the ice reseals, thus trapping them under the ice -- perhaps a great distance from the next breathing hole. Seems like an interesting question to me. Please [edit] your post to *explicitly* indicate what type of research you've already done. (You say you've "come up short", but where did you specifically look and what have you learned along the way?)

Comment: This HIGHLY apocryphal blog post (https://thealchemistskitchen.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-penguins-do-it-testing-waters.html) suggests that some groups of penguins test water by pushing their leader off and seeing whether it's safe. However, I couldn't find any scholarly references that back that up (or otherwise suggest that penguins test water or ice). Regardless, I just wanted to caution against concluding that they don't just because it hasn't been specifically studied. A lack of research on the topic doesn't necessarily indicate that the phenomenon doesn't exist.